# dragging a vertex

Tags: modeling

I am new to blender. when I try to move a vertex in a mesh instead of simply moving the vertex it creates a new cell, how can I disable this option so that when I drag the vertex it should easily move to the new location without creating a new cell.

[image: i want to move the marked vertex][image: but it creates this new cell]

Comment: Perhaps you have a different mode selected in edit mode?

Comment: i am just learning the software. I didn't change any default settings

Answer (score 2):

Are you extruding individual verts to create geometry and filling them using Fill command?

This normally happens  when there are duplicate verts created when this method is used.

`Selecting all verts and removing doubles` will remove any duplicate verts and will not create  any additional geometry when the space between the verts is  filled.

[image]

Comment: FYI this was changed to "Merge By Distance" in Blender 2.8x. It is under the settings "Clean Up".